# MySQL Preference Pane is specifying a port number when it runs mysqld

Tags: mysql

As it says above. When I run mysqld using the preference pane for MySql, one of the arguments it is providing is --port=3307.

Does anyone know how I might go about changing this?

Operating System is OSX 10.10.4
MySQL version is 5.6.26

Comment: Please add your current operating system and the MySQL version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may change the port in the file com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons by editing it with

```
sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Change the port at

```
  <string>--port=3307</string>
```

near the end of the file to whatever you need it to be and reboot your Mac or restart the service.

Comment: I tried that on OSX 10.10.5, and only see binary data in Nano. Running `file /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` gives me `Apple binary property list`. Am I doing something wrong or has this changed somehow very recently?

Comment: @MJV Please change the plist format with `plutil -convert xml1 some_file.plist`. You may have to prepend "sudo"

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new again. (Probably should have googled that myself, though.) Went with JSON but that's a personal preference.